# Looping through results in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, jquery-events

I get stacked on a looping issue and couldn't get it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    FB.api({
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=' + temparray[i]
    }, function (response) {
        for (var x = 0; x < count; x++) {
            $("#divfather" + x).html(response[0].name);
        }
    });
}
```

The second loop is done through `response[0].name` which is the name of Facebook and showing me the same response for all divs.

I want only this second loop being done to the `i` variable.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hard to understand what you want, but I assume you only want the `i` from the outer `for` loop.

You'll need to create a new variable scope in order to retain it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    FB.api({
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=' + temparray[i]
    }, (function( j ) {  // <---- create a function...

                // v---------...that returns a function...
            return function (response) {

               $("#divfather" + j ).html(response[0].name);

            };

        })( i ) // <------...and invoke it immediately, passing "i"
    );
}
```

---

Here's the same thing, but using a named function, which I think is a little nicer.

```
function get_callback( j ) { 

    return function (response) {

       $("#divfather" + j ).html(response[0].name);

    };

}
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    FB.api({
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=' + temparray[i]
    }, get_callback( i ) );
}
```

---

Or personally, I'd place all the logic in the function instead of splitting it up.

```
function set_up_FB_api( j ) { 
    FB.api({
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=' + temparray[ j ]
    }, function (response) {

       $("#divfather" + j ).html(response[0].name);

    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    set_up_FB_api( i );
}
```

Comment: heh good work @patrick :) I completely missed what he was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have a scope issue sken boy.

You are using `i` in the outer loop and then redeclaring it in the inner loop.

Change the second loop to some other letter like `x`.